# redirecting jsp page from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

Here i want to call jsp page from the servlet using RequestDispatcher,the problem is calling the java code in the jsp code is fine and the problem is the html code is not working

Here is the code:

RedirectServlet.java:

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {               
        System.out.println("calling doPost() ");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=WINDOWS-1256");
    String action=request.getParameter("action");
    System.out.println(action);

    if(action.equals("reports")){
        System.out.println("inside reports");



        //Getting values from Reports_arb.jsp
        String Fromdate=request.getParameter("FD");
        String Todate=request.getParameter("TD");
        String status=request.getParameter("actionid");
        String usercode=request.getParameter("usercode");

        //placing given values in a session 


        request.setAttribute("FD", Fromdate);
        request.setAttribute("TD", Todate);
        request.setAttribute("actionid", status);
        request.setAttribute("usercode", usercode);


        //Redirecting to showReport_arb.jsp
        //response.sendRedirect("showReport_arb.jsp");

          ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
          sc.getRequestDispatcher("/showReport_arb.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }
```

showReportt_arb.jsp:

```
  <HTML dir="rtl">
 <HEAD>
 <%@ page 
 language="java" import="java.sql.*"
 contentType="text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1256"
 pageEncoding="WINDOWS-1256"
 isThreadSafe="true"
 autoFlush="true"
 import        ="com.iton.eoffice.WorkflowManagement.*,com.iton.eoffice.contentmanager.*,com.iton.eoffice.authentica       tion.*,com.iton.eoffice.*"
  import   ="java.sql.*,java.util.GregorianCalendar,java.util.Calendar,java.util.Vector,java.text.DateFormat,jav      a.text.SimpleDateFormat"
 %>

 <%
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
  response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  %> 
 ...
 ...
 <script language="JavaScript">
function formatTable(oTable)
 {
var rows=document.all(oTable).rows;
 for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++)
{
if(i%2==0) 
{
  for(var j=0;j<rows[i].cells.length;j++)
  {
    rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    rows[i].cells[j].style.borderTop="1 solid #FFFFFF";
    rows[i].cells[j].style.borderBottom="1 solid #FFFFFF";
    rows[i].cells[j].style.color = "#000000";
  }
} 
...
...
</script>
  ....
 <%
  ...

 System.out.println("From Date is"+FD);
 out.println("welcome to showreports_arb.jsp"); 
 String dtArray[]=FD.split("-");
  FD=dtArray[1]+"-"+dtArray[0]+"-"+dtArray[2];....
 .....
%>
 .....
 .....
 ......

 <TABLE align="center">
                        <TR>
                             <TD class="set"><input type="button"        class="SETARB" value="ØÈÇÚÉ ÇáÊÞÑíÑ" style="width:80px"  onclick="printPage()"></TD>

                            <TD class="set"><input type="button"       class="SETARB" value="ÎÑæÌ" style="width:80px" onclick="closePage()"></TD>
                        </TR>
                    </TABLE>
   <TABLE width="100%" style="border:0px solid #BFBDBA;text-align:center;" align="center">
 ......
 ...
 ..
  </html>
```

in the above logic java code is displaying in the server console but the html code was not displayed.Please help me to resolve  this issue

Comment: Perhaps the html is in a scriplet? Can you post the rest of the jsp page?

Comment: @clav thanks for your response.just now i updated the code please check it once.here i written out.println statement in the scriplet but it is not displayed in the browser.i think it is contentencoding problem so please check it once and resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

its better to user try catch block. may be if exception will be thrown no catch block is there to catch the exception and because of that jsp may not render.